# Run Form1 for 5 times than close Form1, restart

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I'd like to add a loop to:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

This will run `Form1` for 5 times with 3 second delay than close all, than do it again.
I'm using this code to open them manually;

```
Form1 form = new Form1();
form.Show();
```

And I need to stop the loop with;

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

I'm new to coding and if you can explain it with code examples I would be grateful.

Comment: What do you mean by run 5 times? You mean make 5 form1s and show them with 3 sec delays?

Comment: you want to open Form1 every 3 seconds and close all forms when it reaches 5. and start and stop this process by clicking button5 . right?

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary yes exactly.

Comment: You *must* use a Timer to do that.  A for() loop will cause the UI to freeze and prevents "button6" from working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure why you ever want this. But here is the way.

You need a `Timer` with interval of 3000 milliseconds (3 seconds) that will fire an Event at every interval. Inside that Event you will Open up forms and will close all the forms if 5 forms are opened.

```
Timer _timer = new Timer(); // This is the timer

List<Form> forms = new List<Form>(); // This will hold list of forms.

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _timer.Enabled = !_timer.Enabled; // toggle event with this button.
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) // initialize timer with form load event
{
    _timer.Interval = 3000; // set interval
    _timer.Tick += OpenUpForm; // set event
}

private void OpenUpForm(object sender, EventArgs e) // this is the event that should be fired every 3 seconds
{
    if (forms.Count == 5) // if forms reached 5 attempt to close all
    {
        // ForEach will perform this actions for every form in forms list
        forms.ForEach(f =>
        {
            f.Close(); // close form
            f.Dispose(); // free resources
        });
        forms.Clear(); // clear the list
        return;
    }
    forms.Add(new Form()); // add a new form to list
    forms.Last().Show(); // show the form
}
```

Note that this will just open empty forms. If you want to open specific form you should create a 5 copy of that and put them inside list. and just open and close them.